# face This error file building docker image dlib

Tags: python, docker, flask, face-recognition, dlib

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vktrpqpq
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/
> Complete output (53 lines):
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> package init file 'dlib/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
> running build_ext
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
> out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
> return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py", line 223, in 
> setup(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line
> 144, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line
> 223, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py", line 129, in run
> cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
> File "/tmp/pip-install-oho_tlt5/dlib/setup.py", line 122, in get_cmake_version
> raise RuntimeError("\n*******************************************************************\n" +
> RuntimeError:
> *******************************************************************
> CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
> *******************************************************************
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib

---

### DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR ./app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
        && apt-get install -y --fix-missing\
        && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR ./app
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -U pip wheel cmake
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

first install **cmake** and **wheel** with **pip**, the packages you install from the requirement.txt file are first downloaded and then installed, for this reason it fails to install **dlib**.

Answer (score 0):

In your requirements.txt put CMake as first